# How to compare a LinkedList value with its parent object?

Tags: java

How can I get the index of the object I added to a linkedList by comparison? Following code will elaborate my question. (I have showed a dummy linkedList function to just explain the issue)

```
    LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        String j = "HELLO";
        list.add(j);
        System.out.println(list.findOccurrenceOfCurrentItemInList(j) + ""); // should display the value of i
    }
```

Comment: Why would you need that? You already have the value of `i` in the loop?

Comment: @Rohit yes you are right, but what if it were a foreach type loop?

Comment: is this particular requirement with same content in list and checking index, a real time valid requirement?

Comment: @Anas. Check onto the `LinkedList` API. You need [`LinkedList#lastIndexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.Object))

Comment: @Rohit no I do not need that. Imagine a list containing of lots of same values at random locations. I want to know the exact location of an object I added not the first or last occurrence of a similar value.

Comment: @Jayesh no, I have just created this sample for understanding of a concept, if it exists. My actual requirement together with code is somewhat tricky to be posted here as it is.

Comment: I'm with @RohitJain on this: `add` always adds to the end of the list, so you can use `i` or `list.size()` to get to that index.

Comment: @Thilo see my comment above regarding the real issue

Comment: @Anas. Then you have to write a custom method yourself. There is no built-in method for that.

Comment: @Rohit right you are but can you write it for me here? I am confused :(

Comment: @Anas. You've already got an answer below.

Comment: @Anas you can add more that 1 identical object to collection and then your problem is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String args[])
{
    LinkedList<String> dataList = new LinkedList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i < 5;i++)
    {
        dataList.add("test"+i);
    }

    System.out.println(dataList.indexOf("test3"));

}

}
```

I hope it will help you.....

Answer (score 3):

Ok, if you need reference comparison, you must use something like that: (not tested)

```
static <T> int indexOfRef(Iterable<T> src, T value) {
    int i = 0;
    for (T it : src) {
        if (it == value)
            return i;
        ++i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

For going in reverse order, make iterator that goes from end to beginning and change counter accordingly.

Note that in LinkedList you cannot find element faster than O(n) (linear search), and `List<T>` implements `Iterable<T>`, so you can get compatibility with some other types for free.